# Importing data from CSV to MySQL using python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, csv

I am currently working on a schoolproject, and im trying to import data from a CSV file to MySQL using python. This is my code so far:

```
import mysql.connector
import csv

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', password='abc123!', db='jd_university')

cursor = mydb.cursor()

with open('C:/Users/xxxxxx/Downloads/Students.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Student (First_Name, Last_Name, DOB, Username, Password, Phone_nr,'
                       'Email, StreetName_nr, ZIP) '
                       'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")',
                       row)

mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

When i run this, i get this error: "mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '%s' for column 'DOB' at row 1"

The date format used in the CSV file are yyyy-mm-dd

Any tips on this would help greatly!

Comment: Can you please show us the first three rows of sample data? Does it include a header row containing the column names?

Comment: You should log some sample data in you question like `print(row)` for debug purpose.When finish remove it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need to quote the `%s` placeholders.
- Since you're using `DictReader`, you will need to name the columns in your `row` expression (or not use DictReader and hope for the correct order, which I'd not do).

Try this:

```py
import mysql.connector
import csv

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="127.0.0.1", user="root", password="abc123!", db="jd_university"
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()

with open("C:/Users/xxxxxx/Downloads/Students.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        values = [
            row["First_Name"],
            row["Last_Name"],
            row["DOB"],
            row["Username"],
            row["Password"],
            row["Phone_nr"],
            row["Email"],
            row["StreetName_nr"],
            row["ZIP"],
        ]
        cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO Student (First_Name, Last_Name, DOB, Username, Password, Phone_nr,"
            "Email, StreetName_nr, ZIP) "
            "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
            values,
        )

mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working, the error i got earlier is now gone. However, if the ZIP column in the database is an INT value, how would i fix that?

Comment: Replace that `row["ZIP"]` with `int(row["ZIP"])` so you're doing the conversion before you pass the values to MySQL.

Comment: Thanks so much! Data is now imported to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Validate the datatype for DOB field in your data file and database column. Could be a data issue or table definition issue.